# No overload for method 'Equals' takes '0' arguments

Tags: c#, datareader

I am trying to fix an error I am getting in the code below line 34 and 35.

```
aliq.ALIQUOT_ID = reader["ALIQUOT_ID"].Equals();
aliq.SAMPLE_ID = reader["SAMPLE_ID"].Equals();
```

Both Aliquot_ID and Sample_ID are integers. However, the way I wrote those lines
I am getting the following error:

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'Equals' takes '0' arguments C:...App_Code\DAL\DAL.cs    34. 
Error   2   No overload for method 'Equals' takes '0' arguments C:...App_Code\DAL\DAL.cs    35.
```

How should I write these two lines in order to fix this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;


namespace Data
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for DAL
/// </summary>
public class DAL
{
    public static Model.Aliquot GetAliquot_ID(int aliqID)
    {
        string cs =         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        OracleConnection conn = null;
        OracleDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new OracleConnection(cs);
            string oracle = "SELECT SAMPLE_ID, ALIQUOT_ID, MATRIX_TYPE FROM LIMS.ALIQUOT WHERE ALIQUOT_ID = '" + aliqID + "'";
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(oracle, conn);
            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            Model.Aliquot aliq = new Model.Aliquot();
            aliq.ALIQUOT_ID = reader["ALIQUOT_ID"].Equals();
            aliq.SAMPLE_ID = reader["SAMPLE_ID"].Equals();
            aliq.MATRIX_TYPE = reader["MATRIX_TYPE"].ToString();
            return aliq;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            //Add Logging
            HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn("Error", "Error in GetAliquot_ID()", exp);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null) reader.Close();
            if (conn != null && conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Equals()` expects an argument which is the item you are testing equality against e.g. `Item.Equals(AnotherItem)`

Comment: `aliq.ALIQUOT_ID = System.Convert.ToInt32(reader["ALIQUOT_ID"]);`

Comment: Also note that equals returns a bool which is probably not what you want to assign aliq.ALIQUOT_ID and aliq.SAMPLE_ID as?

Comment: What is `.Equals()` supposed to do? The exception is self explanatory, don't call `Equals()` with `0` parameters. The fix depends on what its supposed to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to return the value from the table associated to ALIQUOT_ID and SAMPLE_ID which are integer, like MATRIX_TYPE in the following line which is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equals() doesn't make much sense in that context. What are you trying to do? Convert those results to int, right?

So instead of

```
aliq.ALIQUOT_ID =reader["ALIQUOT_ID"].Equals();
```

use

```
aliq.ALIQUOT_ID =Convert.ToInt32(reader["ALIQUOT_ID"]);
```

Comment: Great! Yes, I am trying to convert the result to int. Thanks @khlr. The issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `.Equals()` from the end of each line.  Assuming that the field in your table for each of these is an integer, then the `reader[<fieldname>]` will give you the associated value.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136163(v=vs.110).aspx) says about the OracleDataReader column indexer:

> Gets the value of the specified column in its native format given the
>   column name.

So, you should be able to remove .Equals() from those lines.

If that doesn't work, try:

```
Convert.ToInt32(reader["ALIQUOT_ID"])
```

Hope that helps